# ReactJS Deployment with Docker on Elastic Beanstalk - Randomly timing out and/or failing

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a basic react-app, created by create-react-app. And I am trying to deploy it to an elastic beanstalk environment, with Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.15.2. Related files that I am using for docker are like below:

`Dockerrun.aws.json` :

```
{ "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": { "Name": "somename/somethingelse", "Update": "true" },
  "Ports": [ { "ContainerPort": "80"}],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Each time I am trying to deploy with 'eb deploy', I am sort of randomly getting outputs like:

```
Creating application version archive "app-XXXX_XXXXX".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2020-08-04 03:28:01    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-08-04 03:28:09    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: TimeoutError - The EB CLI timed out after 10 minute(s). The operation might still be running. To keep viewing events, run 'eb events -f'. To set timeout duration, use '--timeout MINUTES'.
```

And although the console seems still trying to deploy, eventually it gets back to 'Severe' state. Then I run the command again to deploy.

After going through other forums and docs, I have tried to delete app versions, restart the elastic beanstalk env, and try to run the command again. And still, sometimes I am still getting the above error.

Today, tried to switch from `enhanced` health monitoring to `basic` one based on the comments on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=725728, and after one more restarting of elastic env, the deployment seemed okay. I have not tried further deployments yet, to still unsure if changing health monitoring would actually fixes the issue.

Anyone may help me to deal with this slowness/timeout/deployment error issues for docker? Or are there any other ways to deploy a react application to elastic beanstalk?